# How can I convert JSON into javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap, timestamp, flot

I've passed a Java HashMap as JSON to the client side.
The resulting JSON is as follows:

```
{
  "2013-02-27T07:25:35.000+0000": 40,
  "2013-03-01T07:25:35.000+0000": 33,
  "2013-02-26T07:25:35.000+0000": 25,
  "2013-02-23T07:25:35.000+0000": 54,
  "2013-03-03T10:12:59.000+0000": 26,
  "2013-03-02T07:12:59.000+0000": 25
}
```

But for plotting onto Flot charts I need the input in the following format:

```
[
[1328983200000, 40],
[1328983200000, 33], 
[1328983200000, 25],
[1328983200000, 54],
[1328983200000, 26], 
[1328983200000, 25]
];
```

where the first value is Unix Timestamp X 1000

*(The time series support in Flot is based on Javascript timestamps, i.e. everywhere a time value is expected or handed over, a Javascript timestamp number is used. This is a number, not a Date object. A Javascript timestamp is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. This is almost the same as Unix timestamps, except it's in milliseconds, so remember to multiply by 1000!)*

How can I convert it? Can anyone kindly guide. :(

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried doing this: hashMap.entrySet().toArray(); Didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list = {
    "2013-02-27T07:25:35.000+0000": 40,
    "2013-03-01T07:25:35.000+0000": 33,
    "2013-02-26T07:25:35.000+0000": 25,
    "2013-02-23T07:25:35.000+0000": 54,
    "2013-03-03T10:12:59.000+0000": 26,
    "2013-03-02T07:12:59.000+0000": 25
}, arr = [];

for (var key in list) {
    arr.push([+new Date(key)*100, list[key]]);  //One simple line of code
}                                               //Keep trying!


console.log(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/F4tst/

Comment: Why do you multiply "Date(key)*100"?

Comment: @some_coder - Because you have to multiply it by 100 to match up with OP's expected result.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks a lot, @Derek. And I'm surely a bit embarrassed by your inline comment, but take that as constructive criticism. I should have tried harder. Thanks for guiding me!

Comment: @LittleLebowski - Sorry, I might be a little too harsh on the comment part. Changed. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is iterate through the object, create a Date object out of the date you have, use the getTime() method to get the timestamp in milliseconds, create a new array, then push it onto your main array. This may not be the best solution, but it will work.

Assuming your JSON object is named obj;

```
var mainArray = [];
for (var x in obj) {
    var tmpDate = (new Date(x)).getTime();
    var smallArray = [tmpDate, obj[x]];
    mainArray.push(smallArray);
}
```